# SQL Server Management Studio Skin / Appearance / Layout

Tags: ssms

Can you apply a custom skin / appearance to SSMS?  I am thinking something along the lines of a dark theme (black background, yellow font) you'd find in most IDEs

Comment: You can but involves a bit of hackery Have a look at this post:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112379/how-to-change-mssql-management-studio-theme/112380#112380

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SSMS 2012 is build on the VS 2010 shell.  Thus, it can use compatible ".vssettings" files to apply custom color schemes.

See also http://studiostyl.es/ for a gallery.

Answer (score 71):

I decided to try something simple on **SSMS 2012**:

1. Go to http://studiostyl.es/
2. Pick a theme and download it
3. Follow these [screenshot instructions](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mycargus/sets/72157651330521998/)

Note that doing this will only affect the theme of the text editor, not the toolbar, menu, object explorer window, etc.

Comment: @RononDex I don't see that error in Chrome version 47.0.2526.106 on Mac El Cap. Does the link work in a different browser?  Here's an alternative link (same address): http://bit.ly/1kf3vAp

Comment: the flickers instructions are for SQL Server Mgt Studio 2012... 

Tools → Import and Export Settings → Import Selected Env Settings → Browse → [Select your downloaded .vss file] → WIN!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SSMS 2016 (or later) you can use the Microsoft's own Dark theme once you've enabled it.

You can find instructions at Kyle Parrish's blog post titled [Enable "Dark" Theme in SQL Server Management Studio 2016](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/136505-enable-dark-theme-in-sql-server-management-studio-2016)

Comment: Same trick works for SSMS 17.  It's fairly half-baked, but at least it does the main toolbars and the text-editor.  The right-click menus are quite ugly though, so be wary.  Hope they finish it up in 2017 or 2018.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

For SSMS 18:

There is already a default dark theme which is removed by key.
You need to go to following file, go to section "Remove Dark theme" and comment the key out. The you will find the dark-theme in the settings. (Menu>Options>Environment/General - Color Theme)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.pkgundef

```
// Remove Dark theme
//[$RootKey$\Themes\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}]
```

I found also a nice solution on a website that has a prepared powershell statement to change this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.pkgundef') -replace '\[\`$RootKey\`$\\Themes\\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}\]', '//[`$RootKey`$\Themes\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}]' | Out-File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms.pkgundef'"
```

( Source: https://www.sqlshack.com/setting-up-the-dark-theme-in-sql-server-management-studio/ )

Answer (score 0):

Here is my dark theme which you can download:

https://stingrae.com.au/dark-theme-for-microsoft-sql-management-studio.aspx

Comment: Your link is broken.. pls revise.

Comment: Hi yes, sorry ... changed my site. New link half-way down here:
https://stingrae.com.au/

Comment: What versions does it target?